# Remove if exists all character before _

Tags: php

```
function categoriesIdsFunction($ids){
    //I try with preg_replace remove if exists all character before _
    $ids = preg_replace('/^[^_]*_\s*/', '', $ids);

    $ids = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $ids);
      return "in ('" . str_replace(",","','",$ids) . "') ";
}

$categories_in_article = "267,267_463,267_462";

$categories_in_article_return = categoriesIdsFunction($categories_in_article);
```

With my code I take this: in ('463','267_462'),
I try with preg_replace remove if exists all character before _ ($ids = preg_replace('/^[^*]**\s*/', '', $ids);)

I need this return: in ('267','463','462')

Comment: `return preg_replace('/\d+_/','',$ids);`

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol, you are the only person who get what I ask, others who gave me minus should learn to read more carefully.

Comment: I gave you a minus. "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol, it is very useful for me and I make mistake you don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

I can't get what you need to return. If you need an array, you can try this:

```
$result = array_map(function (string $item) {
    return preg_replace('.+_', '', $item);
}, explode(',', $categoriesInArticle));
```

also, you can `implode(',', $result)` to get string w/o `_` sign.

Answer (score 0):

Is some thing like this you want ? 
out put : `in ('267','463','462')`

```
function test2()
{
    $categories_in_article = "267,267_463,267_462";
    $stringArray = explode ( "," , $categories_in_article);
    $categories_in_article_return = "in (";
    foreach($stringArray as $string){
        $categories_in_article_return .=       
        $this->categoriesIdsFunction($string).",";
    }
$categories_in_article_return = rtrim($categories_in_article_return,",");
$categories_in_article_return .= ") ";
echo $categories_in_article_return;
}

    function categoriesIdsFunction($ids){
        //I try with preg_replace remove if exists all character before _
        $ids = preg_replace('/^[^_]*_\s*/', '', $ids);

        $ids = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $ids);
        return "'".str_replace(",","','",$ids)."'";
    }
```